# Using Malloc, Difference between sizeof(int) * numRows and sizeof(int * [numRows])

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Rather simple memory allocation, but I can't my head around.

What is the difference between:

```
int **ans = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*[numRows]));
```

and

```
int **ans = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*numRows);
```

I get heap buffer overflow using the second version, but what is the actual difference here?
I try to allocate x amount of memory block type int.
The difference is

> sizeof(int) * numRows

vs

> sizeof(int * [numRows])

Comment: The cast `(int**)` is unnecessary.

Comment: `sizeof(int)*numRows)` is a size of `numRow` `int`s. `sizeof(int*[numRows])` is a size of array of pointers to `int`. Totally different things

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.  The two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: You're trying to allocate an array of pointers, so the fundamental type is `int *` not `int`. Hence, the second one should be `sizeof(int *) * numRows`.

Comment: Incidentally, these examples are the reason I always make my pointer asterisks part of my type (i.e. `int**`), instead of part of the variable (despite the prevailing fashion).

Comment: To avoid some of this, how about: `int **ans = malloc(sizeof(*ans) * numRows);`?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case

```
int **ans = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*[numRows]));
```

there is allocated memory for an array of `numRows` elements of the type `int *`.

In the second case

```
int **ans = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*numRows);
```

there is allocated memory for an array of `numRows` elements of the type `int` and the allocated memory is interpreted as an array of elements of the type `int *` instead of `int`.  So you can invoke undefined behavior if you will suppose that the memory stores an array with elements of the type `int *` because in general `sizeof( int * )` can be unequal to `sizeof( int )`. But even if they are equal such a call will only confuse readers of the code an will be a potential bug

Comment: What is the difference between int * and int ?

Comment: @Metio_1993 int * is a pointer type to objects of the type int. int is a integer objects.

Comment: @Metio_1993 For example in general sizeof( int * ) can be unequal to sizeof( int )

Answer (score 1):

`int * [numRows]` is not a multiplication expression, it's a *type* - it's an array of pointer to `int`.  So `sizeof (int * [numRows])` is the size (in bytes) of an array of `int *` that's `numRows` elements wide.

`sizeof (int) * numRows`, OTOH, is a multiplication expression - you're multiplying the size of an `int` by the number of rows.  So, let's make some assumptions:

```
numRows        == 10;
sizeof (int)   ==  4;  // common on most platforms
sizeof (int *) ==  8;  // common on most 64-bit platforms
```

So, `sizeof( int * [numRows])` gives us the size of a 10-element array of `int *`, which would be 80.  `sizeof (int) * numRows` gives us the size of 10 `int` objects, which is 40.

A cleaner and less error-prone way of writing that `malloc` call would be

```
int **ans = malloc( sizeof *ans * numRows );
```

Since `ans` has type `int **`, the *expression* `*ans` has type `int *`, so `sizeof *ans` is the same as `sizeof (int *)`.  So we're allocating enough space to hold `numRows` instances of `int *`.

Remember that `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function - the syntax is

```
sizeof ( type-name ) |
sizeof expression
```

It's a unary operator, which has higher precedence than a multiplication operator, so

```
sizeof *ans * numRows
```

will be parsed as

```
(sizeof *ans) * numRows
```